# Revoking false close votes from multiple users

Tags: discussion, support

I recently viewed a question that I initially though was a duplicate of another question, so, I voted to close it as such. Anyway, I asked for clarification just in case it wasn't a duplicate. After clarification from OP and a subsequent edit, I realized that it wasn't a duplicate and I revoked my close vote.

The problem is, someone had already seconded my close vote. Not knowing that a clarification and an edit from OP showed that the question is not a duplicate, that someone never revoked one's vote. What should we do in this case? Can we somehow notify the person who voted to reconsider his decision? Was that someone already notified but decided to leave the vote as is?

The [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116364/how-to-calculate-a-difference-between-current-and-previous-location-vectors-usin) in question.

Comment: When you say that someone else has also voted to close the question as a duplicate do you mean that it still showed the "close (2)" under the question? Or was the question already closed? In the latter case you can notify anyone that has interacted with a post with an "@" in front of their username in a comment. It autocompletes for people that wrote a comment, but it doesn't autocomplete for editors, close voters, mods that added a post notice, the OP, ... - but it still works (you just have to be careful about writing the correct username).

Comment: @Secespitus The question wasn't closed, but there were two votes to close it, mine and another's. I do not know who the other voter is, so I can't notify him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off no, there are no notifications around casting a close vote/flag.

Now to the closing mechanics.
The only thing you can do is retract your CV (close vote). When a post has at least one CV it goes to the close votes review. There users either vote to close it (add more votes), or leave open (jump starts the aging process).
All CVs automatically age away on their own. So if this question does not get another four CVs in a week, I think I remembering that correctly, then that one vote will disappear.

If that someone else who also voted to close it comes back to that post they too can retract their vote.
However that is unlikely for a few reasons, most prominently there is no reason to go back to that post (the only place to retract that vote). There is no notification, mentions or status of your CVs. You just click the button, then if you do not go back to that post you forget about it.

---

Now do not worry, there is still one other thing you can do (although not really needed for something like this), bring it to the mods attention. We can kill CVs, or if it gets that far reopen the question (any 3k user can *vote* to reopen a post, we can do it instantly). So if I had the link *hint hint* I could clear all this up for you right now.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I added the question in question to the question. That was a lot of questions in a single sentence.